# Thrown exception appears to be blocking other threads

Tags: c#, windows, sockets, exception, proxy

Background/Intro:

Very strange issue, where upon a specific exception being thrown, it appears all other threads cease to execute until the exception is handled. The application is a proxy server, piping multiple requests (many hundreds in any one time frame) via a pool of tcp sockets, which connect to N other proxy clients over a socks connection. This has also been tried by passing a delegate, as opposed to using an exception, with the same poor performance results.

A log snippet under normal operation:

```
14:40:17.700 [PrxSvc:9058] --> [200] 1217ms http://redact.example.com   
14:40:17.700 [PrxSvc:9058] C-DEBUG:C                
14:40:17.716 [PrxSvc:9058] --> [200] 1098ms http://redact.example.com           
14:40:17.716 [PrxSvc:9058] C-DEBUG:C             
14:40:17.727 [PrxSvc:9054] --> [200] 905ms http://redact.example.com   
14:40:17.727 [PrxSvc:9054] C-DEBUG:C         
14:40:17.778 [PrxSvc:9050] --> [200] 453ms http://redact.example.com           
14:40:17.778 [PrxSvc:9050] C-DEBUG:C         
14:40:17.781 [Unnamed Thread] C-DEBUG:A          
14:40:17.781 [Unnamed Thread] C-DEBUG:B         
14:40:17.796 [PrxSvc:9058] --> [200] 652ms http://redact.example.com             
14:40:17.796 [PrxSvc:9058] C-DEBUG:C                
14:40:17.807 [PrxSvc:9056] --> [200] 1555ms http://redact.example.com              
14:40:17.807 [PrxSvc:9056] C-DEBUG:C           
14:40:17.816 [PrxSvc:9064] --> [200] 396ms http://redact.example.com
```

The socket pool resuses connections to domains, however when a connection is closed by an external server, we obviously receive no notification of this. When we try to reuse this connection via our TcpSocksHandler.TaskHandler method:

```
socks.Send(buffer, 0, rcv, SocketFlags.None);
socks.Receive(new byte[1], 0, 1, SocketFlags.Peek);
```

This exception is caught with the following:

```
catch
{
    //The socket is bad, we should get a new socket.
    Log("This socket has expired! - Server has closed the connection.");
    Log(String.Format("This socket was {0} seconds old: {1}", seconds, socks.Guid));
    socks.Dispose();
    Log("C-DEBUG:1");
    throw new SocksSocketFailureException(); //throw exception. to bubble back up.
}
```

This is then caught by it's calling code, multiple times up the stack as follows:

```
DoHandleRequest{...
try
{
    _actualEndPoint = TcpSocksHandler.TaskHandler(socket, context.SocksSocket, 30000000, method);
}
catch (SocksSocketFailureException ssfe)
{
    context.SocksSocket = null;
    Logger.Log("C-DEBUG:2");
    throw;
}
}

ProxyBase.HandleRequest{...
    try
    {
        ...
        success = DoHandleRequest(context, out bytes);
    }
    catch (SocksSocketFailureException ssfex)
    {
        Logger.Log("C-DEBUG:3");
        throw;
    }
}

ProxyManager.HandleRequest{
    while (true)
    {
        // Pick the best available proxy to handle the request
        Logger.Log("C-DEBUG:A");
        IProxy proxy = GetNextProxy(context) ?? NullProxy.Instance;
        Logger.Log("C-DEBUG:B");
        try
        {
            // Process the request
            proxy.HandleRequest(context);
            Logger.Log("C-DEBUG:C");
            break;
        }
        catch(SocksSocketFailureException ssfex)
        {
            Logger.Log("C-DEBUG:4");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

From the log snippet below you can see the performance of this (or lack thereof)

```
14:40:34.090 [PrxSvc:9068] C-DEBUG:A             
14:40:34.090 [PrxSvc:9068] C-DEBUG:B                  
14:40:34.231 [PrxSvc:9068] This socket has expired! - Server has closed the connection.
14:40:34.231 [PrxSvc:9068] This socket was 6.281049 seconds old: 61cc51b9-f121-4529-9649-7defcc1f5586           
14:40:34.231 [PrxSvc:9068] C-DEBUG:1            
14:40:34.528 [PrxSvc:9068] C-DEBUG:2              
14:40:34.715 [PrxSvc:9068] C-DEBUG:3              
14:40:34.918 [PrxSvc:9068] C-DEBUG:4             
14:40:34.918 [PrxSvc:9068] C-DEBUG:A
```

No log lines have been edited from the above - Nothing else is processed for pretty much the entire second! (where we could usually handle maybe a hundred requests).
In addition, the mere act of bubbling an exception up the stack seems to take a second (sometimes more!).
- Please take note of the timings of the above log lines. e.g. .2 seconds gap between DEBUG:3 and DEBUG:4 !!

I have NO idea what could be causing this. ANY advice/ideas would be much appreciated!

**UPDATE:**

Based an Eamon's question, I pushed the same x64 build to a non-production local machine, running Windows8 64bit. Installed as a service, release build, as the previous example is. The only other difference is it's now targeting 4 proxy nodes (PrxSvc 9050, 9052, 9054, 9056), as opposed to the previous 80.
I can no longer say if those exception steps are blocking thread execution now, because they are executed in a timely fashion:

```
16:53:59.787 [PrxSvc:9056] This socket has expired! - Server has closed the connection.
16:53:59.787 [PrxSvc:9056] This socket was 0.1280009 seconds old: 69d12cc9-9456-47db-86b2-a2ebf87b41bf
16:53:59.787 [PrxSvc:9056] C-DEBUG:1
16:53:59.787 [PrxSvc:9056] C-DEBUG:2
16:53:59.787 [PrxSvc:9056] C-DEBUG:3
16:53:59.787 [PrxSvc:9056] C-DEBUG:4
16:53:59.787 [PrxSvc:9056] C-DEBUG:A
```

On this machine, the code is currently happily processing 800 concurrent requests at a rate of around 80 requests per second, and could easily process more...
What on earth could be causing this difference?!

For completeness I reran the first test (on the win2008 server) with 4 nodes, instead of 80, and got the same rubbish result:

```
17:22:44.891 [PrxSvc:9054] C-DEBUG:B
17:22:45.063 [PrxSvc:9054] This socket has expired! - Server has closed the connection.
17:22:45.063 [PrxSvc:9054] This socket was 25.84375 seconds old: cfdee74d-9941-4c8c-80cd-f32aa14b7877
17:22:45.063 [PrxSvc:9054] C-DEBUG:1
17:22:45.485 [PrxSvc:9054] C-DEBUG:2
17:22:45.751 [PrxSvc:9054] C-DEBUG:3
17:22:46.016 [PrxSvc:9054] C-DEBUG:4
```

Comment: Some extra info would be nice.  How did you compile the app - Release/Debug x86/x64?  Which .NET version is targetted, and which are you running on?  Is the debugger attached?  Are you running on a machine with visual studio installed?

Comment: Oh, and how long are the stacktraces; i.e. how deep is the deepest stack?

Comment: Sure;
Release build, running on Server 2008 R2 Standard. x64.
Targeted at both 4.0 Framework, and 4.5 (same result each time).
No debugger attached when observing the problem. The machine does not have visual studio installed (it's a production machine).

Comment: The largest stack traces are ~20 frames.
See link to pstack image: http://i.imgur.com/8AXKe.png

Comment: One thing you're doing wrong is that empty catch. Instead of `catch`, use `catch (Exception ex)`. Then use `ex` as the InnerException of your `SocksSocketFailureException`

Comment: Ok, so your stacks are shallow.  The reason I ask about VS being installed is that it sets up some hooks to allow the debugger to be attached whenever an (uncaught) exception occurs and I've previously observed that these cause overhead that goes away when there are no user sessions (i.e. no local, remote desktop or disconnected interactive logins).

Comment: I still think your best bet is that some kind of exception event handler is being triggered, something like the [FirstChanceException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.firstchanceexception.aspx) event, and that this event handler does something bad such as marshal the exceptions to some external sink thus enforcing a single order of execution.

Comment: Have you profiled the code and perhaps tried to find some unexpected calls?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer for your question, what the error in your program is, but that I can hardly tell without seeing the big picture or test your code myself. Normally I would write a comment for this, but my text is too long.

Your first example log ("normal operation") is a bit confusing for me. There are just one `C-DEBUG:A` and `C-DEBUG:B` while at least for every `C-DEBUG:C` there has to be one of each, hasn't it?

The other examples are looking good, everything occurs as I would expect (*A => B => exception => 1 => 2 => 3 => 4 => A*). Well, it seems there is just one thread, but the examples give no clue that this is wrong; i see no second `C-DEBUG:A` from another thread. What do you expect instead?

Regarding to your update: Here I'm wondering more about the performance of your test machine, because every throw of an exception needs some execution time. This is the reason why throwing exceptions in a loop is a big performance hit. The times of your server seems a bit slow, but ok from my point of view.

**While beeing not able to give you a hint for your problem, at least I can give you the statement that the exception throwing itself is not the blocking factor for other threads.** To prove that I wrote a little program (see source code below if you want to know how I've done that). The output of that program was

```
19:31:09.2788 [Thread-0] 0
19:31:09.2788 [Thread-1] 1
19:31:09.3908 [Thread-0] 0
19:31:09.3908 [Thread-1] 1
19:31:09.4908 [Thread-1] 1
19:31:09.4908 [Thread-0] 0
19:31:09.5908 [Thread-0] 0
19:31:09.5998 [Thread-1] Caught exception callstack frame 29
19:31:09.6078 [Thread-1] Caught exception callstack frame 28
19:31:09.6148 [Thread-1] Caught exception callstack frame 27
19:31:09.6218 [Thread-1] Caught exception callstack frame 26
19:31:09.6288 [Thread-1] Caught exception callstack frame 25
19:31:09.6358 [Thread-1] Caught exception callstack frame 24
19:31:09.6418 [Thread-1] Caught exception callstack frame 23
19:31:09.6488 [Thread-1] Caught exception callstack frame 22
19:31:09.6548 [Thread-1] Caught exception callstack frame 21
19:31:09.6608 [Thread-1] Caught exception callstack frame 20
19:31:09.6668 [Thread-1] Caught exception callstack frame 19
19:31:09.6728 [Thread-1] Caught exception callstack frame 18
19:31:09.6778 [Thread-1] Caught exception callstack frame 17
19:31:09.6828 [Thread-1] Caught exception callstack frame 16
19:31:09.6888 [Thread-1] Caught exception callstack frame 15
19:31:09.6908 [Thread-0] 0
19:31:09.6938 [Thread-1] Caught exception callstack frame 14
19:31:09.6978 [Thread-1] Caught exception callstack frame 13
19:31:09.7028 [Thread-1] Caught exception callstack frame 12
19:31:09.7078 [Thread-1] Caught exception callstack frame 11
19:31:09.7128 [Thread-1] Caught exception callstack frame 10
19:31:09.7168 [Thread-1] Caught exception callstack frame 9
19:31:09.7218 [Thread-1] Caught exception callstack frame 8
19:31:09.7258 [Thread-1] Caught exception callstack frame 7
19:31:09.7299 [Thread-1] Caught exception callstack frame 6
19:31:09.7339 [Thread-1] Caught exception callstack frame 5
19:31:09.7369 [Thread-1] Caught exception callstack frame 4
19:31:09.7409 [Thread-1] Caught exception callstack frame 3
19:31:09.7439 [Thread-1] Caught exception callstack frame 2
19:31:09.7469 [Thread-1] Caught exception callstack frame 1
19:31:09.7499 [Thread-1] Caught exception callstack frame 0
19:31:09.7509 [Thread-1] 1
19:31:09.7919 [Thread-0] 0
19:31:09.8509 [Thread-1] 1
19:31:09.8919 [Thread-0] 0
19:31:09.9509 [Thread-1] 1
19:31:10.0509 [Thread-1] 1
19:31:10.1509 [Thread-1] 1
19:31:10.2509 [Thread-1] 1
19:31:10.3509 [Thread-1] 1
```

As you can see, thread *Thread-0* prints a `0` while the exception of *Thread-1* works its way up the callstack. No blocking here!

For reference here my program:

```
class Program {
    class MyException : Exception {}

    // A class for give the starting thread operation some parameters
    class ThreadStartParameter {
        // For identifying each thread
        public int Id { get; set; }

        // For building up a deeper callstack frame
        public int CallStackDepth { get; set; }

        // Indicates that this thread should throw an exception
        public bool ThrowException { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        // Create two threads and let them run concurrently
        Thread t0 = new Thread(BuildUpCallStack) { Name = "Thread-0" };
        Thread t1 = new Thread(BuildUpCallStack) { Name = "Thread-1" };
        t0.Start(new ThreadStartParameter {
            Id = 0,
            CallStackDepth = 0,
            ThrowException = false
        });
        t1.Start(new ThreadStartParameter {
            Id = 1,
            CallStackDepth = 0,
            ThrowException = true
        });
        Console.Read();
    }

    // Recursive helper method to build a callstack of 30 frames, which
    // is used to rethrow an exception at each level
    static void BuildUpCallStack(object data) {
        ThreadStartParameter parameter = (ThreadStartParameter)data;

        if (parameter.CallStackDepth < 30) {
            try {
                BuildUpCallStack(new ThreadStartParameter {
                    Id = parameter.Id,
                    CallStackDepth = parameter.CallStackDepth + 1,
                    ThrowException = parameter.ThrowException
                });
            } catch (MyException e) {
                Log(string.Format("Caught exception callstack frame {0}",
                    parameter.CallStackDepth));
                // If an exception occured, rethrow it unless this
                // callstack frame was the first
                if (parameter.CallStackDepth != 0) throw;

                // If this frame was the first in callstack, restart the
                // thread but this time without throwing an exception (for
                // demonstrate such a restart character like your Proxies do)
                BuildUpCallStack(new ThreadStartParameter {
                    Id = parameter.Id,
                    CallStackDepth = 0,
                    ThrowException = false
                });
            }
            return;
        }

        DoSomething(parameter);
    }

    static void DoSomething(object data) {
        ThreadStartParameter parameter = (ThreadStartParameter)data;

        for (int counter = 0; counter < 7; counter++) {
            if (counter == 3 && parameter.ThrowException)
                throw new MyException();

            Log(parameter.Id);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }

    static void Log(object message) {
        Console.WriteLine(
            "    {0:HH:mm:ss.ffff} [{1}] {2}",
            DateTime.Now,
            Thread.CurrentThread.Name,
            message.ToString());
    }
}
```

If you try this program on your test machine, I guess you should start more "good" threads (which don't throw an exception) and/or increase the needed callstack depth for seeing the effect like I did.

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions are cheap to throw and expensive to catch. Do not catch exceptions unless the code knows how to handle them. This seems to be the case with C-Debug:2 and C-Debug:3. Also you have a known condition that the other side has closed it's connection. You should not be using exceptions to handle this. You need to expose a method or property similar to `IsConnected` and check that in your loop instead of relying on the exception being thrown:

```
while(true) {
   IProxy proxy = GetNextProxy(context) ?? NullProxy.Instance;
   if (!proxy.IsConnected)
       continue;
   try {
     proxy.HandleRequest(context);
     break;
   } catch {
     // handle actual exceptional cases here
   } 
}
```

You could add a counter or timer to the code above and throw an exception in the case that x number of retries or a specific time period has expired if need be, but in any case the IsConnected property check will increase the performance of your code greatly.

Comment: Exceptions are caught because they have to be caught, the pasted code is a very much cut down version of the actual code, there are a number of other exception cases that are being caught in all instances, including the base Exception class.

Using exceptions to bubble up the stack is I agree somewhat undesirable, however again there is a significant amount of code that hasn't been included in the above to make it easier to highlight the actual problem. Using exception's was a desision made to keep the code cleaner, while minimizing the refactoring time.

Comment: The problem is not that exceptions are being thrown, but that they are taking hundreds of milliseconds to process, and blocking all other execution. Note the same result was achieved by passing a delegate down as opposed to using an exception, there was no improvement in performance and it made the code significantly harder to follow.

I'm also unable to change the IProxy interface without a significant amount of refactoring.
If it would solve the issue, I would most certainly give it a go, but I strongly suspect something else is going on?
Especially given the variance on operating systems.

Comment: I would still review the places where exceptions are being caught. It takes an extreme amount of execution time to unwind the stack every time an exception is caught in order to build the exception object. Also, when you have performance issues in correctly operating code "cleanliness" __usually__ goes out the window.